# Release with Debug in Flex/Air?

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, air

I am having one of those nasty "works in debug but not in release" bugs.  Is there any way to build a release version of the app but also debug it?  Some platforms allow for this... but I haven't found a way to do it with my Flex/Air app.

Comment: If you include the automation libraries as a compiler arguement and include them in the release (used for FlexMonkey or HP QTP) you may be able to debug to a certain extent?

Comment: I figured out my problem... forgot to add `-keep-as3-metadata+=META_WHATEVS` as a compiler setting... good ol' `println` debugging... The question still stands, though.  Would have been nice to have.

Comment: You can run release AIR application with adl tool and get traces from it in console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No, not in an easy fashion.

Long Answer: Definitely possible, but you need to work in the logs yourself.  You should look at [SpiceFactory's Logger implementation](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.4/manual/spicelib-logging.php#intro); it's very good.  You could have those logs be sent to a server periodically if you wanted to.  Furthermore, you could always use something like [FlexSpy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/) in your application to see what's going on.

It all depends on how much 'debugging' that you want in a release version while keeping in mind that anything added will decrease performance.

Comment: FlashFirebug for Firefox would be along the lines of FlexSpy also

Comment: FlashFirebug just display traces in firebug, which needs the debug version to be deployed, last I checked.  You could use [ThunderBolt AS](http://code.google.com/p/flash-thunderbolt/wiki/ThunderBoltAS3) which has an 'internal' console for log traces.

Comment: OP said it was an AIR app so firebug isn't so useful here.  To contribute to the list of tracers/loggers, I've been quite happy with [MonsterDebugger](http://www.monsterdebugger.com/).

Comment: I figured the answer was "no".  I was really talking about using the code debugger... in Air.  Some platforms will allow you to build an app with all the release settings BUT include debug symbols so your debugger can still work with it.  It is nice to have when there is a behavior difference between the two builds.

Comment: @Brian,  Well, tell you the truth, there isn't much difference between debug and release versions *other* than the metadata and optimization of code for smaller swf filesize.  Personally, I like to have a lot of logging anyways which is used in the release.

Comment: @J_A_X - how do you go about logging for your release versions?

Comment: @Brian, `private const logger:Logger = LogContext.getLogger(ThisClassName);` then `logger.info('Authentication Successful!');`.  This of course is using [spicefactory's logging framework](http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/2.4/manual/spicelib-logging.php#intro) which can be easily made into a log that's sent periodically to the server or have it send over something when there's an error.  That part of the implementation is up to you, and I suggest that if you do have a general public facing application to have a lot of logging for these kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some "debugging" without modifying your SWF using [SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger).